# AUV Lipo Battery capacity

Tags: battery, underwater, lithium-polymer, auv

I'm making an AUV that requires 15-20 minutes of operating time. I'm using 6 of these motors ([Blue Robotics T200 Thrusters](https://www.bluerobotics.com/store/thrusters/t200-thruster/)) for propulsion; I'm looking for **6S lipo batteries** (22.2V) but i don't know how to calculate the **capacity** (mAh) I need to run my vehicle. Is there any **formula** that allows me to calculate the required parameter?

*Parameters required: Battery capacity, Maximum underwater operation time @ given load.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't gave all information that are needed for such calculations. However, the technical details of the Thrusters give a peak consumption of 350 Watts each. So you have 6 of them, makes overall 2.1kW/h.

Lets **assume** your Batteries have the following details: 6S 22.2V 3300mAh.
Therefore the amount of energy the Batterie stores is: 22.2V*3.3Ah = 73.26W/h.

Moreover **assume** that you will drive only 25% full-speed in Average, 2.1kW/h * 0.25 = 525W/h.

Let's calculate the runtime under these **assumptions**: 73.26W/h / 525W/h = 0.139542857h * 0.6 = 0,083725714 minutes runtime.

So if you want to archive 20minutes operation time reaarange the formula:
525W/h * (1/3h) *((== 20 minutes))* = ~158Wh / 22.2V = ~7.1Ah

So you need a battery which have at least 7.1Ah capacity at 22.2V, assuming an average load of 0.25%.

Please consider, you will have a peak-load of 25A * 6 = 150A. This means the given battery (7100mAh) needs to support a minimum discharge current of 150A/7.1A = 21.12C. 
**If you don't respect these you battery might begin to burn, causing harm to your vehicle and the Environment".**

Moreover you don't gave information about the consumption of any electronics inside the AUV, therefore this are not in the scope of this post.

Comment: Electronics inside the AUV have a separate power source, so I didn't really mention it. The weight of the bot will be negligible i.e we'll be balancing the buoyancy so that it has 0 weight. Please tell me if any other information is required.

Comment: I rearranged the equation to give you a rough approximation for 20 minutes. I assumed a typical load of 25% based on my AUV experienced. I already assumed you vehicle has a neutral weight in water ;)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but will I need some form of cooling mechanism for the lipo? It's in a closed environment (obviously ) so I'm a bit worried about the heat generated. Prior experience with quadcopters tells me that I should do something about it, but I'd like to know your opinion on this.

Comment: It would be great to have this question as an additional question, because it's unrelated to the original one. However: From my experience additional cooling even with mobile i7 CPUs with LiFePo4 cells it is not needed. However I Have had much bigger cells and used much less discharge levels. I recommend to have a few temperature sensors. The heat dispensation depends on the hull material (AlMg3 in my case). So an estimation is again really hard to make.